# Unable to copy value from hidden field into another HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

Using link

https://demo.owncloud.org/index.php/apps/files/?dir=/&fileid=2

I want to use the hidden field

**HTML**

```
<div id="controls" style="width: 1100px; min-width: 1100px;">
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="crumb svg last" data-dir="/">
        <a href="/index.php/apps/files?dir=/">
            <img class="svg" src="/core/img/places/home.svg" alt="Home">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button view-switcher" id="gallery-button">
    <div id="button-loading"></div>
    <img alt="Gallery view" src="/core/img/actions/toggle-pictures.svg" class="svg">
</div>

<div class="actions creatable" style="">
    <a class="button new" href="#" data-original-title="" title="">
        <span class="icon icon-add"></span>
        <span class="hidden-visually">New</span>
    </a>
    <div id="uploadprogresswrapper">
        <div id="uploadprogressbar">
            <em style="display:none" class="label outer">
                <span class="desktop">Uploading...</span>
                <span class="mobile">...</span>
            </em>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="" style="display:none" class="stop icon-close">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="file_action_panel" activeaction="false"></div>
<div class="notCreatable notPublic hidden">
    You don’t have permission to upload or create files here
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="permissions" value="31" name="permissions">
<input type="hidden" value="537919488" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" id="max_upload">
<input type="hidden" value="537919488" id="upload_limit">
<input type="hidden" value="979339338" id="free_space">
<input type="hidden" value="(max )" class="max_human_file_size">
```

**Javascript**

The relevant section for the JS is show below, please view

```
if (response.data !== undefined && response.data.uploadMaxFilesize !== undefined) {
                $('#max_upload').val(response.data.uploadMaxFilesize);
                $('#free_space').val(response.data.freeSpace);
                $('#upload.button').attr('data-original-title', response.data.maxHumanFilesize);
                $('#usedSpacePercent').val(response.data.usedSpacePercent);
                $('#owner').val(response.data.owner);
                $('#ownerDisplayName').val(response.data.ownerDisplayName);
                Files.displayStorageWarnings();
```

to be displayed using code

```
My name is <span id="free_space"></span> ...!!!
```

The code is not working, I tried it with `firebug`

**working code(try)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('dem0').value=document.getElementById("free_space").value
   </script>
  My name is <span id="dem0"></span> ...!!!
```

**solved**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var e=document.getElementById("free_space").value;
 document.getElementById("dem0").textContent=e;

   </script>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here. We don't go "outside" to fix things.

Comment: Both of those elements have the same ID

Comment: `id="free_space"` this is supposed to be a unique Identifier, I can't verify your Javascript since you didn't post it here but I'd wager that's the problem

Comment: @Culyx i have improved my question.

Comment: You still have not added the Javascript necessary - please read our [mcve] page for hints on how to improve this question

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is document.getElementById("free_space").value  which will return the value of that element, whether or not it's hidden.  If you want it to display in the <span id="free_space"></span> you will need to give that a separate id and then you can set it to the value of "free_space"

Comment: @MichaelS please show working example, I'm confused why Id should be different should it not refer to Id whose value I want to use.

Comment: all id's should be unique, It's similar to if you were in a room with 2 people named Bob, and you call out "Hey Bob, give me your number!" ... both would probably say "which one, him or me?"If you have Bob and Sam, you can say, "Bob, give me your number!" and then give it to Sam.

Similarly, we need 2 different id's on the elements.  If they both have the same id, it doesn't mean they are linked in any way, they just have the same name.  So you get the value from one ("free_space" or whatever) and then pass it to the other ("new-id" or whatever)

Comment: Hmmm, I just saw your js code, now I'm confused... the value is coming from a response.data?  I thought the value was coming from <input type="hidden" value="979339338" id="free_space"> and going to <span id="free_space"></span>  Is the data going to both the hidden element and the <span> element?

Comment: @MichaelS please see my working code, its not working but the logic i think is close to be correct. I used your notes for writing code.